# Searching for a input character in an input string P2 in Python

Tags: python

My current code works but not how i want it to work. Currently if i enter a word i.e. "compc"
and then search for the character "c"
the output will be:

```
'c' found at index 0
Sorry, no occurrences of 'c' found at index 1
Sorry, no occurrences of 'c' found at index 2
Sorry, no occurrences of 'c' found at index 3
'c' found at index 4
```

but what i want it to do is only show:

```
'c' found at index 0
'c' found at index 4
```

If no characters were found then simply:

```
Sorry, no occurrences of 'c' found
```

My current code is:

```
print("This program finds all indexes of a character in a string. \n")

inStr = input("Enter a string to search:\n")
searchChar = input("\nWhat character to find? ")
searchChar = searchChar[0]

anyFound = False
startAt = 0


index = startAt


while index < len(inStr):
    if inStr[index] == searchChar:
        anyFound = True


    if anyFound == True:
        print ("'" + searchChar + "' found at index", index)
        index = index + 1
        anyFound = False


    else:
        anyFound == False
        print("Sorry, no occurrences of '" + searchChar + "' found")
        index = index + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
print("This program finds all indexes of a character in a string. \n")

in_str = input("Enter a string to search:\n")
search_char = input("\nWhat character to find? ")
search_char = search_char[0]

any_found = False

for index, char in enumerate(in_str):
    if char == search_char:
        print("'%s' found at index %d" % (search_char, index))
        any_found = True

if not any_found:
    print("Sorry, no occurrences of '%s' found" % (search_char))
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, although I was trying to figure out what's wrong with my code. Although it would be more efficient in a for loop, i'm trying to accomplish the task within a while loop. Any ideas on that?

Comment: You have to print  `Sorry...` after `for`, not inside `for`.

Answer (score 0):

change your while loop structure:

```
anyFound = False #initialize as False
while index < len(inStr):
    if inStr[index] == searchChar:
        print ("'" + searchChar + "' found at index", index)
        anyFound = True #will change if any are found
    #don't do anything if the char is not the same
    index = index + 1

#following code will only run if anyFound wasn't changed
if not anyFound: 
    print("Sorry, no occurrences of '" + searchChar + "' found")
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with your code, this seems to solve them all for Python 2:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
print("This program finds all indexes of a character in a string. \n")
inStr = raw_input("Enter a string to search:\n")
searchChar = raw_input("\nWhat character to find? ")
searchChar = searchChar[0]
anyFound = False
startAt = 0
index = startAt
while index < len(inStr):
    if inStr[index] == searchChar:
        anyFound = True
        print "'" + searchChar + "' found at index " + str(index)
        index = index + 1
    index += 1
if not anyFound:
    print("Sorry, no occurrences of '" + searchChar + "' found")
```

The improvements I've made are:

1. use `raw_input` instead of `input` so users can type just `abca` instead of `"abca"`
2. move the last check outside of the while

Comment: you dont need to increment index outside of your while loop anymore :)

Comment: @RNar true! copy pasting madness.

Comment: also, using his use of brackets for the `print` function as a reference, i think that OP is using python 3; where there is no `raw_input` function.

Comment: Makes a lot of sense, Thank you. Positioning the increments is one thing i need to work on for sure. I removed the redundant ones however in the if statements. Also @R Nar i am using python 3, but i am able to convert the differences :) /Note; raw_input just isn't a valid function for me, however i do not have to use "string" either way.

Answer (score 0):

I'd move your `anyFound` boolean outside and only set it once you've found something. I kept everything else pretty similar to what you had except I brought out the index increment.

```
anyFound = False
while index < len(inStr): 

    if inStr[index] == searchChar:
        print ("'" + searchChar + "' found at index", index)
        anyFound = True

    index = index + 1

if not anyFound:
    print("Sorry, no occurrences of '" + searchChar + "' found")
```